# How to make a caption exactly middle and center of a image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` inside which, there are image and a span. Like this

```
<div class = "image">
    <img src = "example.png" alt="myimage"> 
    <span class = "caption">
        Hello World.!
    </span>
</div>
```

The CSS I wrote is:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

This works, but when I add more text in `.caption` i need to manually reduce the `left: x%;`. Is there any way to make it middle centered to the image? I am new to CSS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make it caption width 100% and make it center align

Comment: @ShaileshPatel no. That didn't work.!

Comment: You have specified `left` twice for class _caption_. That's not gonna help.

Comment: if you know width of caption you can apply width and using margin auto and left 0 and right 0 you can make it caption center align. suppose width will be 150px you can use this properties {width:150px; left:0; right:0; margin:auto;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here is a live [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/z9psc2f8/1/).